# Regexp to find C comments

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I need a regexp in Ruby to find the comment before a C instruction.

For example I have this file `example.c`

```
/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 1
 */
x = rb_define_class_under (foo, "MyClassName1", bar);

/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 2
 */
y = rb_define_class_under (foo, "MyClassName2", bar);

/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 3
 */
z = rb_define_class_under (foo, "MyClassName3", bar);
```

Then I have my parser in ruby `parser.rb` like this:

```
content = File.open('example.c').read

if content =~ /((?>\/\*.*?\*\/))([\w\.\s]+\s=\s)?rb_define_class_under.*?"(MyClassName1)"/m
  puts "Comment number 1 is:"
  puts $1
end

if content =~ /((?>\/\*.*?\*\/))([\w\.\s]+\s=\s)?rb_define_class_under.*?"(MyClassName2)"/m
  puts "Comment number 2 is:"
  puts $1
end

if content =~ /((?>\/\*.*?\*\/))([\w\.\s]+\s=\s)?rb_define_class_under.*?"(MyClassName3)"/m
  puts "Comment number 3 is:"
  puts $1
end
```

Now the output I expect is this:

```
Comment number 1 is:
/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 1
 */
Comment number 2 is:
/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 2
 */
Comment number 3 is:
/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 3
 */
```

But I get:

```
Comment number 1 is:
/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 1
 */
Comment number 2 is:
/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 1
 */
Comment number 3 is:
/*
 * COMMENT NUMBER 1
 */
```

Any idea? What is the right regexp to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `.*` to the beginning of the regex.

Currently the `.*?` after `rb_define_class_under` in your regex is causing you to always match and capture the first part of the string, and the `.*?` matches up until the class name you are actually looking for.

By adding a greedy match at the beginning of the regex you make sure that you only start your capture group at the last `/*` before the class name you want.

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/Orja089zAI

Note that you still match from the beginning of the string, but the first capture group is the correct comment.